# Apache/PHP Segmentation fault

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to solve this issue for about 2 months now.

I'm running xampp 5.6.3 64 bits ( apache 2.4.10 and php 5.6.3 )

In my apache error_log I get this:

```
[Mon Dec 29 20:53:49.172435 2014] [core:notice] [pid 15389] AH00051: child pid 15800 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /opt/lampp/dumps/
[Mon Dec 29 20:53:51.174128 2014] [core:notice] [pid 15389] AH00051: child pid 15917 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /opt/lampp/dumps/
[Mon Dec 29 20:54:02.185605 2014] [core:notice] [pid 15389] AH00051: child pid 15904 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /opt/lampp/dumps/
[Mon Dec 29 20:54:03.186109 2014] [core:notice] [pid 15389] AH00051: child pid 15972 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /opt/lampp/dumps/
[Mon Dec 29 20:54:07.190239 2014] [core:notice] [pid 15389] AH00051: child pid 15942 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /opt/lampp/dumps/
[Mon Dec 29 20:54:22.205090 2014] [core:notice] [pid 15389] AH00051: child pid 15808 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /opt/lampp/dumps/
```

This happens randomly and often ...
I made a core dump of apache and this is what i get:

```
Core was generated by `/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x00007f747374a7d6 in zend_stack_push () from /opt/lampp/modules/libphp5.so
```

I also tried xampp 5.5.19-0 ( apache 2.4.10 and php 5.5.19 ) and still i get the same errors in my error_log. I'm currently running the 5.5.19

The site/scripts that I'm running on this server are very gd intensive.

Any ideeas ?

Comment: Seems some libraries are corrupted. Did you try to re-install ?

Comment: I reinstalled Xampp ( both 5.63 and 5.5.19 ) 2 times.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem : I have developed a WordPress plugin that is very database intensive (the plugin migrates content from a different CMS and try to solve all the internal references). The second feature (adjusting internal references) uses a lot of SELECT queries with the LIKE statement (because I need to search for substrings)  correctly works up to a certain point (that I'm not able to find right now) when the error appears in the apache error_log file

Comment: Mine was a problem of an infinite recursion. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327393/why-does-an-infinitely-recursive-function-in-php-cause-a-segfault

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem and checked my logs. I found a line like this

```
 [25-Dec-2017 20:38:45 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0
```

I moved my Ioncube loader line to top of php.ini

```
zend_extension="ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so"
```

The problem resolved.